# Forward mouse input to jxbrowser running in background

Tags: java, awt, lwjgl, minecraft-forge, jxbrowser

I am trying to embed jxbrowser into a opengl game as a gui.(Actually it's Minecraft, but not relevant in this case)

The drawing part is complete. I can draw the browser UI at anywhere as a quad.

BUT, since the browser is running in background, **I need to forward the user's mouse position to the browser, or the browser's view**.

I've tried the code from [JxBrowser's documentation about forwarding mouse events](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000102480-forwarding-mouse-events), but looks like it only works with [heavyweight widget](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013069-lightweight-or-heavyweight).

I've tried using heavyweight, but it doesn't provide a way to bake into a BufferedImage.

Here's what I got so far:

```
public class BrowserScreen extends GuiScreen {
    private BrowserView view;
    private Browser browser;

    public BrowserScreen(BrowserView view, Browser browser) {
        this.view = view;
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    int browserWidth = 1260;
    int browserHeight = (int) (browserWidth * (float) height / (float) width);

    @Override
    public void initGui() {
        browserHeight = (int) (browserWidth * (float) height / (float) width);
        browser.setSize(browserWidth, browserHeight);
        view.setSize(browserWidth, browserHeight);
        view.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        if (browser == null || view == null) return;

        LightWeightWidget component = (LightWeightWidget) view.getComponent(0);
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) component.getImage();
        if (image == null) return;

        //Bind captured image to opengl
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 3); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int pixel = pixels[y * width + x];
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
                buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
                //buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
            }
        }

        buffer.flip(); //FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

        // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
        // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using
        // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        //Draw the quad
        float pictureRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        float screenRatio = (float) this.width / (float) this.height;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if (pictureRatio > screenRatio) {
            height = (int) (this.width * ((float) height / (float) width));
            y = this.height / 2 - height / 2;
        } else {
            width = (int) (this.height * ((float) width / (float) height));
            x = this.width / 2 - width / 2;
        }
        Gui.drawScaledCustomSizeModalRect(x, y, 0, 0, width, height, this.width, this.height, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMouseInput() throws IOException {
        if (browser == null) return;
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(-1)) {
            BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder builder = new BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder();
            builder.setEventType(MOUSE_PRESSED)
                    .setButtonType(BrowserMouseEvent.MouseButtonType.PRIMARY)
                    .setClickCount(1)
                    .setModifiers(new BrowserKeyEvent.KeyModifiersBuilder().mouseButton().build());
            browser.forwardMouseEvent(builder.build());
            System.out.println("Left clicked");
        }
        int i = Mouse.getEventDWheel();
        if (i != 0) {
            if (i > 1) {
                i = 6;
            }
            if (i < -1) {
                i = -6;
            }
            BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder builder = new BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder();
            builder.setEventType(MOUSE_WHEEL)
                    .setScrollBarPixelsPerLine(25)
                    .setScrollType(WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL)
                    .setUnitsToScroll(i);
            browser.forwardMouseEvent(builder.build());
            System.out.println("Scrolled: " + i);
        }
        super.handleMouseInput();
    }

    @Override
    protected void mouseReleased(int mouseX, int mouseY, int state) {
        if (browser == null) return;
        BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder builder = new BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder();
        builder.setEventType(MOUSE_RELEASED)
                .setButtonType(BrowserMouseEvent.MouseButtonType.PRIMARY)
                .setClickCount(1)
                .setModifiers(BrowserKeyEvent.KeyModifiers.NO_MODIFIERS);
        browser.forwardMouseEvent(builder.build());
        System.out.println("Released");
    }


    @Override
    public void onGuiClosed() {
        dispose();
    }

    private boolean dispose() {
        if (browser != null) {
            if (!browser.isDisposed()) browser.dispose();
            browser = null;
        }
        if (view != null) {
            if (view.isEnabled()) {
                view.setEnabled(false);
                view = null;
                return true;
            }
            view = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static BrowserScreen open(String url) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.CHINA);

        Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
        BrowserPreferences preferences = browser.getPreferences();
        preferences.setTransparentBackground(true);
        browser.setPreferences(preferences);

        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        final BrowserScreen screen = new BrowserScreen(view, browser);

        browser.loadURL(url);
        return screen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events forwarding works in the lightweight mode as well. If you run the sample application from the mentioned [article](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000102480-forwarding-mouse-events) replacing the browser constructor with `Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);`, you should see that it works as expected.

I noticed that you don't define mouse event coordinates when composing the *BrowserMouseEvent* instance.
Please try filling all fields of the *BrowserMouseEvent* instance(similar to the way described in the article).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem myself. It turns out that:

- For every mouse event, I only need to fill in the setX and setY method. The setGlobal method has to be left empty.
- The X and Y values forwarded are calculated incorrectly.
- For the mouse click event, both the MOUSE_PRESSED and MOUSE_RELEASED events have to be called.

And, here's how I pass the MOUSE_MOVED, since it is not in the according documentation:

```
    BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder builder = new BrowserMouseEvent.BrowserMouseEventBuilder();
    builder.setEventType(MOUSE_MOVED)
            .setX(browserX)
            .setY(browserY)
            .setModifiers(new BrowserKeyEvent.KeyModifiersBuilder().mouseButton().build());
    browser.forwardMouseEvent(builder.build());
```